# Is it possible to intercept relation like CategoryProductRelation in Hybris?

Tags: java, spring, interceptor, sap-commerce-cloud

Normally, in Hybris, there are model interceptors such as PrepareInterceptor. That is, when a model changes, it can be intercepted.
I have a problem at that point. I would like to intercept when a change happens related to CategoryProductRelation. Neither CategoryModel nor ProductModel change as a result of that. Just a row changes in cat2prodrel table. That is not a model change situation.

Do you have any offer to intercept when CategoryProductRelation changes?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. In my case, I import INSERT_UPDATE and REMOVE CategoryProductRelation impex.Yes, it is true that neither CategoryModel nor ProductModel changes during these operations but LinkModel changes. I wrote a remove interceptor for REMOVE operation and an after save listener for INSERT_UPDATE operation by looking at 'typeCode'. Here is the my solution.

**AfterSaveListener for INSERT_UPDATE operation**

```
 .....
//'143' is a typeCode of CategoryProductRelation
if(pk.getTypeCode()==143){

  Object model= modelService.get(pk); 
  if(model instanceof LinkModel){
    ......
  }
  .....
}
```

**Interceptor(RemoveInterceptor) for REMOVE operation**

```
 ......
 if(model instanceof LinkModel){
     final LinkModel linkModel = (LinkModel) model;
     PK pk=linkModel.getPk();
     .....
 }
 .....
```